# NSDictionary to TableView

Tags: objective-c, json, ios, uitableview

because i'm a newby at Stackoverflow i cannot comment someones anwser yet. (my reputation is 16..). I got a question about this anwser: [How do I put this JSON data into my table view? Please help me, I'm living in a nightmare :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305595/how-do-i-put-this-json-data-into-my-table-view-please-help-me-im-living-in-a-n/5307071#5307071)

[Fulvio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264802/fulvio-cusumano) sais you have to use  `[eventNameList addObject:event];` and `[eventNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` to store and get the event data but. addObject is an NSMutableSet method and objectAtIndex:indexPath.row is not. So i cannot use this method to get the data from the NSMutableSet.

Besides that, i can use the count methods neither.

Any Idea's ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have an NSDictionary, you could use the [dictionary allKeys] method to retrieve an array with all keys (lets call it keyArray for now). For the rowCount you could return the count of objects in this keyArray. To get the item that needs to be displayed in the cell you could use [dictionary objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] to get the appropriate dictionary for the displayed cell.

In code:

```
// use the keyArray as a datasource ...
NSArray *keyArray = [jsonDictionary allKeys];

// ------------------------- //

// somewhere else in your code ...
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [keyArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      // set some cell defaults here (mainly design) ...
   }

   NSString *key = [keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:key];
   // get values from the dictionary and set the values for the displayed cell ...

   return cell;
}
```

---

**@Tieme:** apparantly the URL you use already returns an array, you don't really need to process a dictionary (you could just use the array as the dataSource), check out the following:

```
SBJSON *json = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my-bjoeks.nl/competitions/fetchRoutes/25.json"];
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id object = [json objectWithString:string error:&jsonError];
if (!jsonError) {
   NSLog(@"%@", object);
   NSLog(@"%@", [object class]); // seems an array is returned, NOT a dictionary ...
}

// if you need a mutableArray for the tableView, you can convert it.
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:object]
```

Comment: NSArray *keyArray = [jsonDictionary allKeys]; gives the following error: -[__NSArrayM allKeysForObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e4e660

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the -allKeys method on an NSDictionary object? Because this method is inherently available to any NSDictionary, but the error you receive suggests you're calling it on another type of object, see: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This does not work: <code>- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // load from json object
    NSString *jsonObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my-bjoeks.nl/competitions/fetchRoutes/25.json"]];
    
    //to parse it i have made a sbjsonparser object
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [[[SBJsonParser new] init] objectWithString:jsonObject error:&jsonError];
    
    // use the keyArray as a datasource ...
    NSArray *keyArray = [parsedJSON allKeys];
    
}</code>

Comment: @wolfgang-schreurs Thanks, that made it happen!

Answer (score 0):

LUCKY:)

Assuming that you might be having nsmutablearray of nsdictionary.

In such case you can get data using:

```
[dictionary objectforkey:@"key"] objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]
```

Comment: doesn't work: *** -[__NSArrayM valueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b72c80

Comment: cell.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"keyname"]];
(arrayList is my nsmutablearray and keyname is key.. You need to make arraylist a class variable.. This works fine with me...

Answer (score 0):

`eventNameList` should be defined as an `NSMutableArray`, not an `NSMutableSet`.  `NSMutableArray` responds to both `-addObject` (it puts the new object at the end of the array) and `-objectAtIndex:` and when you think about it, a table view is essentially an ordered list and so is an array whereas a set is not.

Comment: this looked liked the easies solution but it doesn't work for me, the tableview is still empty and when i use the count method to count the data for the numberOfRowsInSection method i returns 0;

Comment: @Tieme: Put a breakpoint in your count method and check that the array is not nil.

Comment: @Tieme: Put a breakpoint on the line you want it to stop at (click in the margin of the editor window) and then run the program in the debugger.

Comment: thanks, just found it out. The array is indeed nil and i'm about to find out why..